# Application specific log in tomcat 7 using JULI?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm using java system logging in tomcat 7, but no logging statements get written to the log. I've added this file to my WEB-INF/classes. The log file "new-xyz-test" gets created (so I have at least some of the config right) but its empty - no log statements get printed to it.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, org.apache.juli.FileHandler

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level=ALL
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory=${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix=new-xyz-test-

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

com.xyz.level=ALL
com.xyz.handlers=org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

Comment: What is the level that are you using in your logging statements?

Comment: I've tried using FINE, ALL, FINER, INFO...I'm still not getting anything in the logs, but you've been really helpful and (maybe this will help someone else) so I'll mark it fixed. I have to assume its' something anomalous and specific to this application.

Comment: I wish you had marked that answer as 'helpful' instead of 'answered'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To configure JULI in the web applications you need have a `logging.properties` file in the `WEB-INF/classes` directory. If you use the default handlers, you may lose messages.  You need to specify a prefix for the handler in your file.

```
handlers=1FILE.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

1FILE.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level=FINEST
1FILE.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory=/app-logs
1FILE.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix=file-1

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

com.xyz.level=INFO
com.xyz.handlers=1FILE.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

com.abc.level=INFO
com.abc.handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

A
handler prefix (e.g. `1FILE.`) starts with a number, then has an arbitrary string, and ends with a period (.).

- See more in [*Logging in Tomcat*](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)

---

#### Arguments in the JVM

If you are not running the Tomcat from the `startup.sh` or `startup.bat`, you need to specify:

1. The location of the general `logging.properties` for Tomcat (in the `conf` directory of Tomcat)
2. The manager `org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`. This is important because allows you to configure
   for each web application different loggin options. By default, a JVM process can only have a single configuration file.) ,

Similar to the next (I'm using eclipse):

```
-Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Users\Paul\workspaces\utils\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\logging.properties" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

By default, `java.util.logging` read the file that is included in the JDK or JRE, e.g.:

```
"C:\Software\jdk1.7.0_17\jre\lib\logging.properties"
```

- [*Setting Tomcat Heap Size (JVM Heap) in Eclipse*](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/setting-tomcat-heap-size-jvm-heap-eclipse/), for how to add arguments in the VM

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've used this exact syntax (even copying and pasting the example you used) and a log file gets created but no logging entries (the log file is blank). Logging works fine outside of  Tomcat. I'm at a loss as to what's preventing logging.

Comment: The part about the `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` when not using the normal startup scripts is very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that you write to the correct logger , i.e. `Logger.getLogger("com.xyz")`?

I think that you may got wrong when you wrote in logging.properties:`com.xyz.level=ALL com.xyz.handlers=org.apache.juli.FileHandler` in the case that you actually write to the logger `Logger.getLogger(com.xyz.YourClass.class)`, that because in the logging properties file you should write the logger name which is in your case `com.xyz.YourClass`

Comment: In it's current state, this is more a comment than an answer. You could add a more fleshed out example of what you want the original poster to do, but it's a bit short right now!