# Tomcat keeps logging what he wants

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, logging, configuration

well, I've put this logging.properties configuration file to my web apps src directory:

```
    handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = GenTree.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

But I can't find anything that I output in the logs except for console and there are no files starting with GenTree* anywhere...
Does anybody know anything about this? As much as I understand it's probably using the default settings of my jre that tomcat uses. But I want project specific settings for this project.

I mean how am I supposed to set up the logging? Did I miss anything? There's something about logs in tomcats server.xml, should I modify it? I mean haven't found anything about modifying in server.xml in any article about logging in tomcat. But right now Tomcat does seem to be loggin this pattern which is described in server.xml:

```
<!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
```

Can somebody explain please?

Edit: I've checked the JRE directory (JAVA_HOME) and it doesn't have any logging.properties at all...

Comment: Are you using eclipse, with `webapps` directory on the directory of tomcat or on the workspace of eclipse (`.metadata`)?

Comment: @PaulVargas Well I believe yes for the workspace of eclipse, the run configuration of eclipse has the tomcat in -Dcatalina.base="D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7"

Comment: Didn't know TomCat had a gender. Have you tried manually creating your own logs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need add the JVM argument if you are using Tomcat from Eclipse to use [Tomcat JULI](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html) on your web application (`loggin.properties`):

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

Open the run configuration of the server, *Open lauch configuration* 
[image: Tomcat configuration]

Add the argument in the VM arguments:

[image]

See also [*Application specific log in tomcat 7 using JULI*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15753752/870248).

**UPDATE**

I added a clean installation of Tomcat 6.0.36 with Java 7 to eclipse. Next, I created a eclipse project with a listener:

```
package org.paulvargas.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public final class TestListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(ServletContextListener.class.getName());

    public TestListener() {
        LOG.info("LOG directory:" + System.getProperty("catalina.base")
                + File.separator + "logs");
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent evt) {
        LOG.info("TestListener initialized: " + evt);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent evt) {
        LOG.info("TestListener destroyed: " + evt);
    }

}
```

And in the web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TestTomcatJuli</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.paulvargas.test.TestListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

I only added to the default JVM parameters the new what I had said, `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager`.

```
-Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\Paul\indigo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.36" -Dwtp.deploy="C:\Users\Paul\indigo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Software\apache-tomcat-6.0.36\endorsed" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
```

The project structure:

```
C:.
|   .classpath
|   .project
+---.settings
|       .jsdtscope
|       org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
|       org.eclipse.wst.common.component
|       org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml
|       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.container
|       org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.superType.name
+---build
|   \---classes
|       |   logging.properties
|       |
|       \---org
|           \---paulvargas
|               \---test
|                       TestListener.class
+---src
|   |   logging.properties
|   |
|   \---org
|       \---paulvargas
|           \---test
|                   TestListener.java
\---WebContent
    +---META-INF
    |       MANIFEST.MF
    |
    \---WEB-INF
        |   web.xml
        |
        \---lib
```

The logging.properties is the same of your post.

In the console I see:

```
may 27, 2013 1:16:09 PM org.paulvargas.test.TestListener <init>
INFO: LOG directory:C:\Users\Paul\indigo\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\logs
may 27, 2013 1:16:09 PM org.paulvargas.test.TestListener contextInitialized
INFO: TestListener initialized: javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent[source=org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@2f3adb]
```

And have the file `GenTree.2013-05-27.log` with the same output.

None other file have been modified, like `server.xml`, `context.xml` and without extra libraries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think this is it. However I'm still missing something. Do I have to download and add some JULI libraries to Tomcat's lib folder?

Comment: So I added JULI libraries to tomcats lib and web-inf lib folders. I alos added these arguments: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\conf\logging.properties"
Still something's missing. Am I importing the wrong libs maybe? - import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

Comment: Well it kind of did start working with logging.properties location passed in parameter: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\o‌​rg.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp7\conf\logging.properties"
However right now the log messages I send myself are not visible neither in console nor in file at all. Any ideas?