# Java Web Service serving JSON from Objects

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm using Eclipse Luna, Tomcat 7, and Jersey trying to create a simple web service. It all works fine except serving the Objects as JSON. I can make it work by coding Strings by hand or using JSONSimple. But I want to rely on the higher level automatic JSON conversion for this project.

I've been reading the documentation and Googling this all day. But I cant get past:

```
SEVERE: Mapped exception to response: 500 (Internal Server Error)
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class test.model.User, and Java type class test.model.User, and MIME media type application/json was not found.
```

All the examples make it look like it should be automatic.

Can someone please point out what I am missing?

Thanks

lib includes: (not using Maven)

`asm-3.3.1.jar
c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-collections4-4.0.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.jar
commons-math3-3.2.jar
javax.json-api-1.0.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar
jersey-bundle-1.19.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
quartz-2.2.1.jar
quartz-jobs-2.2.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
taglibs-string.jar`

Otherwise I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>test1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>test.util.AppInitListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and:

```
package test.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import test.dao.UserDao;
import test.model.User;

@Path("/users")
public class RestUsers {

    private UserDao userDao;

    public RestUsers(){
        userDao = new UserDao();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public User getUsers() {

        User user = userDao.getUserById(1L);

        return user;

    }

}
```

and:

```
package test.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the users database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String answer;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;

    private String email;

    private String handle;

    private String image;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastlogin;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modified;

    private String name;

    private String passencr;

    private String passhint;

    private String password;

    private String question;

    private String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return this.created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getHandle() {
        return this.handle;
    }

    public void setHandle(String handle) {
        this.handle = handle;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Date getLastlogin() {
        return this.lastlogin;
    }

    public void setLastlogin(Date lastlogin) {
        this.lastlogin = lastlogin;
    }

    public Date getModified() {
        return this.modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassencr() {
        return this.passencr;
    }

    public void setPassencr(String passencr) {
        this.passencr = passencr;
    }

    public String getPasshint() {
        return this.passhint;
    }

    public void setPasshint(String passhint) {
        this.passhint = passhint;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

also...

```
Starting test1: class test.util.AppInitListener
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:04 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:05 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class test.rest.Hello
  class test.rest.RestUser
  class test.rest.RestUsers
  class test.rest.ListConfigs
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:05 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:05 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19 02/11/2015 05:39 AM'
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 06, 2015 6:01:06 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3307 ms
```

Comment: Is the jersey-bundle getting deployed in your WEB-INF/lib directory? Everything looks right and jersey-bundle contains jersey-json which is what you need. You might turn on verbose logging and see if you can tell which mappers are being registered. Jersey 2.x supports the logging on startup to show what providers it has found. Can't remember if 1.x supports this feature.

Comment: jersey-bundle is getting deployed to the directory. But I'm not getting a lot on logging info. see above. Not sure I know how to increase logging just for jersey.. I put a copy of logging.properties in the eclipse server config folder. Not sure it's working tough. I'm new at this part...

Comment: If you are starting your tomcat using eclipse you have to do this in order to get the tomcat server to see your logging configuration. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762798/tomcat-keeps-logging-what-he-wants

Comment: I think the problem may be with your AppInitListener. Just noticed you don't have the packages param configured in your web.xml. So you must be initializing with the AppInitListener. If this is the case you need to probably specify the PojoMappingFeature in there. Can you post the code to that. That is probably your problem. BTW if you want to use jaxb annotations jackson (json lib supports those). If you annotate the User class with @XmlRootElement it will most likely work. Sounds weird but the default handler tries to use the jaxb annotations for serializing json unless you specifiy

Comment: I might have figured it out. I tried a bunch of Jackson jars version 1.x.x instead of the 2.x.x. Spewed out some JSON now... Maybe latest is not always greatest...

Comment: the PojoMappingFeature. I prefer to use the Jaxb xml annotations because my application will support both xml and json even if I don't want to use xml it is nice when someone asks.

Comment: I'm just trying to setup the environment at this point. I've not decided how I want to code stuff yet. Thanks!